# What's the difference between "Import Table address" and "Import Address Table address" in Date Directories of PE?

Tags: portable-executable, datadirectory

[image]

Anyone knows the difference?

Comment: The import table is an intermediate table that points to the portions of the import address table that belong to each dll. The import table organises all the relevant pointers for an imported dll on a dll by dll basis. This includes a pointer to the IAT, but also the ILT, the module name. The IAT address is just a pointer to the whole IAT

Answer (score 9):

If you want to play with Portable Executables, there's no way around grabbing a copy of [the specs](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/pecoff.mspx).

It's been a while, but in case memory serves me correctly: <s>IT and IAT are identical, except that IAT is filled by the PE-loader while resolving imports</s> - but don't take my word for it, check the specs :)

### EDIT:

Had a quick browse through the specs, and refreshed my memory a bit:
The Import Table is the *master structure*, with one entry per DLL you're importing from. Each entry contains, among other things, an *Import Lookup Table* (**ILT**) and *Import Address Table* (**IAT**) pointer (iirc these used to be called `OriginalFirstThunk` and `FirstThunk`). The ILT and IAT tables are identical on-disk, but during runtime the IAT will be filled with the memory addresses of imported functions.

The PE header IAT field probably can't be relied on 100% if you want to be able to deal with nonstandard EXEs, just like you can't depend on the start-of/size-of code and data pointers. It's best to ignore the IAT header field and parse the IT instead. Also, when parsing the IT, the ILT will be missing on some executables, having only the IAT - older borland (iirc) linkers were notorious for not generating the ILT.

### EDIT 2: definitions

- IT: Import Table (PeCoff section 6.4.1) - table of per-DLL `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR`.
- ILT: Import Lookup Table (PeCoff section 6.4.2) - table of per-import `IMAGE_THUNK_DATA`.
- IAT: Import Address Table (PeCoff section 6.4.4) - on-disk: identical to ILT, runtime: filled with imported function memory addresses.

Comment: But you can see from the graph above,they are NOT identical,IT is `517C` while IAT is `5000`

Comment: Identical doesn't mean they point to the same *location*, but that the *contents* are the same.

Comment: *IAT is filled by the PE-loader while resolving imports*, so IAT should be valid only when loaded,say,doesn't exists when in a hex viewer,right?

Comment: It means that on disk, you should see the same byte contents, whereas after loading, the IAT will be modified.

Comment: No,I just inspected the byte contents at IT and IAT on disk,they are different.

Comment: What do you mean by `ILT`? I don't see such a term even in this article:http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/Understanding_imports.html

Comment: @COMer: Import Lookup Table, term from the PECOFF.DOC.

Comment: What's ILT for since there's no info regarding the memory addresses of imported functions? IMO,only runtime filled  IAT is useful.

Comment: @COMer: it's to make Bound Imports possible check [this](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/dynamic-linking-linux-and-windows-part-two) article for a short explanation.

Comment: Is there an updated link to the pecoff specs? This link is either dead or behind a MSFT access program.

Answer (score 3):

@snemarch Is mostly right, though I think both him and the documentation are wrong that the ILT and IAT are the same on disk. I've looked through the bytes, they are not the same.

Though, he is right about the definition and purpose of the tables.

The ILT (Import Lookup Table) is used by the Windows Loader to associate the functions used by an EXE with their address in a DLL. However, once this association is made, the address in the DLL gets written to the IAT (Import Address Table) in the EXE. After the EXE is loaded, it doesn't need the ILT anymore, when it calls a function in a DLL it points into the IAT.

Comment: Yes, everyone is wrong about that. On disk IAT contains bound and delayed import addresses

Answer (score 3):

`IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT` eventually leads to multiple IAT thunks, which are stored in a memory region, which starts at `[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT].VirtualAddress`, and has size `[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT].Size`.

I guess it is useful when all the sections are loaded by default as read-only, and you can use `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT` to make the IAT (but not the ILT) thunks writable.

BTW, ILT and IAT can have different content, when DLL is bound.  In that case, IAT thunks contain the pre-calculated addresses of the imported functions.

Answer (score 0):

The import directory points to an import directory table, which is a table in .rdata, and in the import table, there's an IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR entry for each dll and the entry points to the name string of the dll, the start of the IAT portion for the imports from that dll, and the start of the ILT portion for the imports from that dll.

The bound import directory table is usually in the header page, and contains IMAGE_BOUND_IMPORT_DESCRIPTORs for each bound module. Each descriptor contain a pointer to the bound module name string (also in the header), and a timestamp, which is the timestamp of the dll it's bound to.

The delay import table is usually in .rdata and contains IMAGE_DELAY_IMPORT_DESCRIPTORs for each delay loaded module. IMAGE_DELAY_IMPORT_DESCRIPTORs contain a timestamp, link to module name, link to the delay load IAT and delay load ILT and the bound delay load IAT and the unload delayed import table.

In dwmcore.dll, the .rdata section looks something like (in order): IAT, constant file scope variables, export directory, EAT, ELT, EOT, export function names, more constant file scope variables and strings, delay import table, delay import module names, delay ILT, delay import function names, import table, import module names, ILT, import function names, unwind info.

Delay IAT is actually at the start of .data. I'm not sure if modules share the same delay IAT/ILTs or whether they're separate. I'm not sure why delay and delay bound has separate IAT instead of using the main IAT.

The IAT contains the RVA of the function name string on disk if the function is not bound, delayed or delay bound. If it is bound then the IAT contains an address hint for the function. If it is delayed / delay bound then it contains the address of a helper function. If only [hinting](https://web.archive.org/web/20160324035922/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100317-00/?p=14573/) is used instead of [binding](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/18/9980802.aspx) then the IAT contains an index hint.